# casting strings to timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, pyspark

I want to cast a string to timestamp. The problem I'm facing is that the string shows the 1st three letters of the month, rather than the month number:

E.g. `31-JAN-20 12.03.48.759214 AM`

Is there any smart way to above value into like?

```
2020-01-31T12:03:48.000+0000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_timestamp` to convert the string into timestamp type then use `format_date` to get the desired pattern :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("31-JAN-20 12.03.48.759214 AM",)], ["date"])

df.withColumn(
    "date2",
    F.date_format(
        F.to_timestamp("date", "dd-MMM-yy h.mm.ss.SSSSSS a"),
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"
    )
).show(truncate=False)

#+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
#|date                        |date2                        |
#+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
#|31-JAN-20 12.03.48.759214 AM|2020-01-31T00:03:48.759 +0100|
#+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```